# PHP array explode homework

Tags: php

I have just started to learn php and now I am doing my first homework but i really need help with it.

```
$_heros= <<<_HERO

    1;Marvel;31546720180001;Super;Man;m;06.09.2002
    2;Marvel;31546720190008;Bat;Man;m;26.08.2004
    3;Marvel;31546720190010;Wonder;Woman;f;06.05.2005
    4;Marvel;31546720190013;Black;Widow;f;01.09.2004
    HERO;
```

I have got a heredoc like the one above and i need to split the lines up, so each line is going to be an arry. I have to use the array explode command.
I would be really happy if someone could help me.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php  You know what to do and what to use, what's not working?

Comment: OK, so what help do you need? Just answering the question for you will be a waste of our time and yours, because you won't learn anything. Have a go at the problem yourself, and then post a question with a specific problem.

Comment: It's completely irrelevant, but I can't help noticing that your data's wrong: Batman and Wonder Woman are DC characters, not Marvel 

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your heredoc has an error within it, the Open and Close to it doesn't match (first has a leading `_`) which I've resolved in the below solution.

Get your input string, `explode()` to split it on `\n` (newlines) assuming LF line endings to give you a final array with each line separated out.

```php
<?php
$heroes = <<<HERO
1;Marvel;31546720180001;Super;Man;m;06.09.2002
2;Marvel;31546720190008;Bat;Man;m;26.08.2004
3;Marvel;31546720190010;Wonder;Woman;f;06.05.2005
4;Marvel;31546720190013;Black;Widow;f;01.09.2004
HERO;

print_r(explode("\n", $heroes));
```

That'll give you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1;Marvel;31546720180001;Super;Man;m;06.09.2002
    [1] => 2;Marvel;31546720190008;Bat;Man;m;26.08.2004
    [2] => 3;Marvel;31546720190010;Wonder;Woman;f;06.05.2005
    [3] => 4;Marvel;31546720190013;Black;Widow;f;01.09.2004
)
```

If you also needed to split out the inner content on the `;`, you can apply the same logic something like this:

```php
<?php
$inputData = <<<HERO
1;Marvel;31546720180001;Super;Man;m;06.09.2002
2;Marvel;31546720190008;Bat;Man;m;26.08.2004
3;Marvel;31546720190010;Wonder;Woman;f;06.05.2005
4;Marvel;31546720190013;Black;Widow;f;01.09.2004
HERO;

$heroes = [];
foreach (explode("\n", $inputData) as $line) {
    $heroes[] = explode(';', $line);
}

print_r($heroes);
```

That'll give you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => Marvel
            [2] => 31546720180001
            [3] => Super
            [4] => Man
            [5] => m
            [6] => 06.09.2002
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => Marvel
            [2] => 31546720190008
            [3] => Bat
            [4] => Man
            [5] => m
            [6] => 26.08.2004
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => Marvel
            [2] => 31546720190010
            [3] => Wonder
            [4] => Woman
            [5] => f
            [6] => 06.05.2005
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => Marvel
            [2] => 31546720190013
            [3] => Black
            [4] => Widow
            [5] => f
            [6] => 01.09.2004
        )

)
```